# JPA: Type of ArrayList field in Entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm

I am stuck with an issue while using Hibernate - JPA.

Issue is I am having an entry which is of type ArrayList. This ArrayList can have any type of values, but limited to some primitive ones + String + Timestamp. In short entries which are not entities, but elementary values.

My question here is what type I should use to store this kind of field in the Entity?

Answer (score 1):

@ElementCollection is what you are looking for. This lets you define a mapping for a non-Entity class e.g. Embeddable or Basic.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection

You can also use @CollectionTable to define the table.

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "data" ....)
private List<String> data;
```

Comment: Yes, this is useful when we have collection of a specific generic type. But in my case the list can hold any type of value at a time. The list can have type of String as well as Timestamp at a single instance of time.

I've tried using collection type List without specifying any generic type. But it gives error that EntityManagerFactory is unable to configure because of not specifying any Generic Type.

Comment: Can we use List<Serializable> as type of `@ElementCollection` ?

Comment: Huh? How's your database going to look for that? Last time I checked most RDBMS required a column type definition for each column and 'String or Timestamp' wasn't one of them.

Comment: The intention here is to persist elementary values as type Object, like `List<Object>`. But that is not allowed in JPA. It is giving EntityManagerFactory creation error.

Comment: Firstly, how does your database look for this? Can you provide the definition of the column you want to save these basic types to?

Comment: Well, the logic is already available. As per current logic the data was read from the file as deserialized content. I am not transferring data from file to Database. So there is no database column set as of now.

By looking at the possible values **Object** type field will fit to the requirement. For this field `VARBINARY` database type should be the proper option, to store `List<Object>`.